# Spring Data Rest Add custom endpoint to specific reposiotry

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I would like to add a custom search endpoint to my existing user repository.

My user Repository looks like this:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel="users", path="users")
public interface UserRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<User, Long>{

    User findByUsername(String username);
}
```

The custom controller:

```
@BasePathAwareController 
@RequestMapping("users/search")
public class CustomController implements ResourceProcessor<RepositorySearchesResource>, ResourceAssembler<User, Resource<User>> {
    @Autowired
    UserRepository userReposiotry;
    @Autowired
    private EntityLinks entityLinks;

    @RequestMapping(value = "findFirst", produces = "application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<Resource<User>> findFirstUser() {
          Resource<User> resource = toResource(userReposiotry.findOne(1L));
          return new ResponseEntity<Resource<User>>(resource, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @Override
    public RepositorySearchesResource process(RepositorySearchesResource resource) {
        LinkBuilder lb = entityLinks.linkFor(User.class, "username");
        resource.add(new Link(lb.toString() + "/search/findFirst", "findFirst"));
        return resource;
    }

    @Override
    public Resource<User> toResource(User user) {
        Resource<User> resource = new Resource<User>(user);
        return resource;
    }
}
```

This returns the correct search endpoint for the users:

```
{
  "_links": {
    "findByUsername": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/users/search/findByUsername"
    },
    "self": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/users/search"
    },
    "findFirst": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/users/search/findFirst",
      "templated": true
    }
  }
}
```

But also for other endpoints like Invites:

```
{
  "_links": {
    "findUserByInvite": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/invites/search/findUserByInvite"
    },
    "self": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/invites/search"
    },
    "findFirst": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/invites/search/findFirst",
      "templated": true
    }
  }
}
```

How can this be restricted to the users only?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume your invites endpoint also returns a `RepositorySearchesResource` ?! Your `ResourceProcessor` is invoked whenever spring-data-rest serializes a `RepositorySearchesResource`. If you want different links for users and invites you have some alternatives:

- use different return types for your search endpoints so you can have different `ResourceProcessor` implementations
- put more logic inside your `ResourceProcessor` to differentiate if you are in your invites or users use case

Comment: Hi, The invite is the same as the userRepository interface. Using your second suggestion I managed to do it by adding a      if(resource.getDomainType() == User.class) into my RepositorySearchesResource process. But I have been wondering is there a better way to do it? Thanks

Comment: Hi, Can anyone say me the `ResourceProcessor` alternative in the most recent implementation of Spring? I know [some of the Class Names are changed](https://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/current/reference/html/#migrate-to-1.0.changes.representation-models). But can't find something about `ResourceProcessor` there.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do that is use ResponseBodyAdvice.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class AllEntityBodyAdvice implements ResponseBodyAdvice {

    @Override
    public boolean supports(@NonNull MethodParameter returnType, @NonNull Class converterType) {
        System.out.println("In supports() method of " + getClass().getSimpleName());
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public Object beforeBodyWrite(Object body, MethodParameter returnType, MediaType selectedContentType, Class selectedConverterType, ServerHttpRequest request, ServerHttpResponse response) {
        System.out.println("In beforeBodyWrite() method of " + getClass().getSimpleName());

        if (Objects.equals(request.getMethod(), HttpMethod.GET)) {
             // do sth
        }

        return body;
    }
}
```